# After using cache() in pyspark the row count is wrong

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, caching, pyspark

When I perform a row count operation on my dataframe with/without `cache()`, I get a different result.

The example is the following:

```
videosDF = videosRawDF.withColumn("trending_date", F.to_date("trending_date", "yy.dd.MM"))\
                      .withColumn("publish_time", F.from_unixtime(F.unix_timestamp('publish_time', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")).cast("timestamp"))\
                      .dropna(subset = ["trending_date", "publish_time"])
videosDF.count()
```

> 120746

On the other hand if I only add `.cache()` the result changes

```
videosDF = videosRawDF.withColumn("trending_date", F.to_date("trending_date", "yy.dd.MM"))\
                      .withColumn("publish_time", F.from_unixtime(F.unix_timestamp('publish_time', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")).cast("timestamp"))\
                      .dropna(subset = ["trending_date", "publish_time"])
videosDF.cache()
videosDF.count()
```

> 0

The correct solution after performing the drop is 120746 rows, but I am forced to perform the cache. What I can do?
Thank you for reading.

EDIT:
The dataset can be found in: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/datasnaek/youtube-new
and my code until now is the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType,BooleanType
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

ruta = "gs://ucmbucketrafael/data/"
youtubeSchema = StructType([
    StructField('video_id', StringType(), nullable = True),
    StructField('trending_date', StringType(), nullable = True),
    StructField('title', StringType(), nullable = True),
    StructField('channel_title', StringType(), nullable = True),
    StructField('category_id', StringType(), nullable = True),
    StructField('publish_time', StringType(), nullable = True),
    StructField('tags', StringType(), nullable = True),
    StructField('views', IntegerType(), nullable = True),
    StructField('likes', IntegerType(), nullable = True),
    StructField('dislikes', IntegerType(), nullable = True),
    StructField('comment_count', IntegerType(), nullable = True),
    StructField('comments_disabled', BooleanType(), nullable = True),
    StructField('ratings_disabled', BooleanType(), nullable = True),
    StructField('video_error_or_removed', BooleanType(), nullable = True),
    StructField('description', StringType(), nullable = True)
])

USvideosDF = spark.read.schema(youtubeSchema)\
                       .option("header", "true")\
                       .option("quote", "\"").option("escape", "\"")\
                       .option("mode","DROPMALFORMED")\
                       .csv(ruta+"youtube_USvideos.csv")\
                       .withColumn("pais",F.lit("EEUU"))\
                       .drop("description")

CAvideosDF = spark.read.schema(youtubeSchema)\
                       .option("header", "true")\
                       .option("quote", "\"").option("escape", "\"")\
                       .option("mode","DROPMALFORMED")\
                       .csv(ruta+"youtube_CAvideos.csv")\
                       .withColumn("pais",F.lit("CA"))\
                       .drop("description")

GBvideosDF = spark.read.schema(youtubeSchema)\
                       .option("header", "true")\
                       .option("quote", "\"").option("escape", "\"")\
                       .option("mode","DROPMALFORMED")\
                       .csv(ruta+"youtube_GBvideos.csv")\
                       .withColumn("pais",F.lit("GB"))\
                       .drop("description")

videosRawDF = USvideosDF.union(CAvideosDF).union(GBvideosDF)

videosDF = videosRawDF.withColumn("trending_date", F.to_date("trending_date", "yy.dd.MM"))\
                      .withColumn("publish_time", F.from_unixtime(F.unix_timestamp('publish_time', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")).cast("timestamp"))\
                      .dropna(subset = ["trending_date", "publish_time"])
videosDF.cache()
videosDF.count()
```

Comment: Hi Raphael. A minimal reproducible example would really help us figure out what's going on in your situation.

Comment: Hi Oli, I just uploaded my code and the dataset. Basically it is a reading of a csv and union

Answer (score 1):

I have already discovered the problem. It is the interaction between DROPMALFORMED and the scheme. If the schema is deleted when reading the csv it already works correctly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).